# How to encode json plain text into json data using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

POST plain text (from another API) simulate with postman using plain text

```
{ "name":"brad" , "address":"mystreet" }
```

on Node:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/api/test', function (req, res) {
    var contact = req.body; 
    console.log(contact);
});
```

Got these on the console:

```
{ '{\n"name":"brad",\n"address":"mystreet"\n}': '' }
```

How to make use or convert those text into a JSON data (formatted)?.

Comment: What do you mean by "a JSON data (formatted)"? You either parse the JSON ([How to parse JSON using Node.js?](//stackoverflow.com/q/5726729)), which makes it an object, or you have a string, which you can pretty print ([How can I pretty-print JSON using JavaScript?](//stackoverflow.com/q/4810841)). That output is odd, because it's actually and object, with your JSON string as the name of a property...

Comment: I suspect this is an issue with how you are sending the JSON vis Postman, not an issue with the express code.

Comment: When I'm using `console.log(typeof(req.body)); it print object not a text (NOT plain text).

Comment: When I'm added `var str = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2); it return {
  "{\n\"name\":\"brad\",\n\"address\":\"mystreet\"\n}": ""
}

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.parse` parses valid JSON text into JS objects:

```js
var text = '{ "name":"brad" , "address":"mystreet" }';

var json = JSON.parse(text);

console.log(json);
```

Comment: Should you need this when using `bodyParser.json()`?